# LINQ Grouping dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a class list of records, so user can select to group rows dynamically by property name. For example `MenuText`, `RoleName` or `ActionName`. Then  I have to execute grouping so I need a generic method to handle grouping by passing column name.

Example :

```
public class Menu
{
  public string MenuText {get;set;}
  public string RoleName {get;set;}
  public string ActionName {get;set;}
}

public class Menus 
{
 var list = new List<Menu>();
 list.Add( new Menu {MenuText="abc",RoleName ="Admin", ActionName="xyz"};
 list.Add( new Menu {MenuText="abc",RoleName ="Admin", ActionName="xyz"};
 list.Add( new Menu {MenuText="abc1",RoleName ="Admin1", ActionName="xyz1"};
 list.Add( new Menu {MenuText="abc1",RoleName ="Admin1", ActionName="xyz1"};

  /// columnName :- Name of the Menu class ( MenuText  or RoleName  or ActionName)

  public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,IEnumerable<Menu>>> GroupMenu(string columnName)
  {
          // Here I want to get group the list of menu by the columnName 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're not working with a database you can use Reflection:

```
private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Used as:

```
var grouped = enumeration.GroupBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x, columnName));
```

This is a pretty raw solution, a better way should be to use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx):

```
var grouped = enumeration.GroupBy(columnName, selector);
```

**EDIT** *Dynamic* LINQ maybe needs some explanations. It's not a technology, a library or a brand new framework. It's just a convenient name for a couple (2000 LOC) of helpers methods that let you write such queries. Just [download their source](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) (if you don't have VS samples installed) and use them in your code.

Comment: But I need to retrieve data from Database SQL Server

Comment: can you please refer me any example if you have on dynamic linq

Comment: @ineffablep the last line of code in my answer (where GroupBy accepts a string as parameter). More examples (and information) on the link (line before last code example).

Comment: Unfortunately Dynamic Linq hasn't been updated in years which is why I wouldn't consider recommending it.

Comment: @Romoku "Dynamic LINQ" is just a _name_ for few helpers classes built on the top of **standard** LINQ implementation. There is **nothing to update**...

Comment: It's sorta being updated via community (unofficially) - located here: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic   - But @AdrianoRepetti is correct, there really isn't much to update, its just a nice layer on top of the standard linq.

Comment: Tnx @TravisWhidden, nice link: he also added some examples (as unit tests) which IMO lacked in original code. I updated answer to point to that repo!

Comment: how to use this if i have two groupby conditions?

Answer (score 8):

The following approach would work with LINQ to Objects as well as with LINQ to EF / NHibernate / etc.
It creates an expression that corresponds to the column / property passed as the string and passes that expression to `GroupBy`:

```
private static Expression<Func<Menu, string>> GetGroupKey(string property)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Menu));
    var body = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Menu, string>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Usage with `IQueryable<T>` based data sources:

```
context.Menus.GroupBy(GetGroupKey(columnName));
```

Usage with `IEnumerable<T>` based data sources:

```
list.GroupBy(GetGroupKey(columnName).Compile());
```

BTW: The return type of your method should be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Menu>>`, because an `IGrouping<string, Menu>` already means that there can be *multiple* `Menu` instances per key.

Comment: how to do when it is "dynamic" i.e. I do not know it is "Menu" ? I cannot do typeof(dynamic) and if I do typeof(object) then it will complain that property does not exist on System.Object .

Comment: You will need to pass an instance and call GetType on it

Comment: I have a bag of Expando objects which is nothing but key value pair of strings. What instance should I pass here. There is nothing concrete

Comment: Please ask a new question. This is beyond the scope of the comments

Comment: But basically, an ExpandoObject implements `IDictionary<string, object>` so you should be able to do something as simple as this: `listOfYourExpandoObjects.GroupBy(x => x[columnName])`

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way:

```
if(columnName == "MextText")
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.MenuText);
}

if(columnName == "RoleName")
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.RoleName);
}

if(columnName == "ActionName")
{
    return list.GroupBy(x => x.ActionName);
}

return list.GroupBy(x => x.MenuText);
```

You could also use expression trees.

```
private static Expression<Func<Menu, string>> GetColumnName(string property)
{
    var menu = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Menu), "menu");
    var menuProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(menu, property);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Menu, string>>(menuProperty, menu);

    return lambda;
}

return list.GroupBy(GetColumnName(columnName).Compile());
```

This will produce a lambda `menu => menu.<PropertyName>`.

But there's not really much of a difference until the class gets bloated.

Comment: but this is an example , I am looking generic solution to implement for any Model

Comment: i like that Romoku always has a full answer fast

Answer (score 2):

I have done this with Dynamic Linq as suggested by Adriano

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, TElement>> GroupByMany<TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, params string[] groupSelectors)
    {
        var selectors = new List<Func<TElement, object>>(groupSelectors.Length);
        selectors.AddRange(groupSelectors.Select(selector => DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof (TElement), typeof (object), selector)).Select(l => (Func<TElement, object>) l.Compile()));
        return elements.GroupByMany(selectors.ToArray());
    }

public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, TElement>> GroupByMany<TElement>(
        this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
    {
        if (groupSelectors.Length > 0)
        {
            Func<TElement, object> selector = groupSelectors.First();
            return elements.GroupBy(selector);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: In your second GroupByMany method you have groupSelectors.First(); so the grouping is performed only on the string property of the params array that is passed into the first GroupByMany method. So, I don't get a point..

Answer (score 0):

You solution is simple to implement for any model, I have just made it generic one.

```
public static Expression<Func<TElement, string>> GetColumnName<TElement>(string property)
    {
        var menu = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TElement), "groupCol");
        var menuProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(menu, property);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, string>>(menuProperty, menu);
        return lambda;
    }
```

so called this as below

```
_unitOfWork.MenuRepository.Get().GroupBy(LinqExtensions.GetColumnName<Menu>("MenuText").Compile());
```

Thank you very much for the help.