# LINQ Expression of the Reference Property

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I want to get the LINQ Expression of the Reference Property

I  need to get the Lambda Expression as groupCol=>groupCol.Role.Name

I have tried with the expression but not succeeded , this will work with groupCol=>groupCol.MenuText but not with reference types

```
var menu = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Menu), "groupCol");

// getting  Role.Name' is not a member of type exception
var menuProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(menu, property);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Menu, string>>(menuProperty, menu);



public class Menu
{
  public string MenuText {get;set;}
  public Role Role {get;set;}
  public string ActionName {get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this one property at a time:

```
private static Expression<Func<Menu, string>> GetGroupKey(string property)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Menu));
    Expression body = null;
    foreach(var propertyName in property.Split('.'))
    {
        Expression instance = body;
        if(body == null)
            instance = parameter;
        body = Expression.Property(instance, propertyName);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Menu, string>>(body, parameter);
}
```

This answer extends the `GetGroupKey` method I showed you in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678640/572644).

Comment: Is it possible to do Multi Group By#

Comment: list.GroupBy(e => new { e.MenuText, e.Role.Name});

Comment: @ineffablep: This is more complex. Please post it as a new question and link to this as context. And you need to specify the exact syntax of the string you want to pass. Hint: Passing the string `"new { e.MenuText, e.Role.Name}"` is a bad idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680840/multi-column-group-by-expression-tree

Comment: I mean, I need it in the below format  _unitOfWork.MenuRepository.Get().GroupBy("Role.Name","MenuText")     I have posted in new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680840/multi-column-group-by-expression-tree