# Multi Column Group By Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

As per the post [LINQ Expression of the Reference Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679883/linq-expression-of-the-reference-property)
I have implemented Group By Extension  thanks to Daniel Hilgarth  for the help ,  I need help to extend this for GroupByMany as below

_unitOfWork.MenuSetRepository.Get().GroupBy("Role.Name","MenuText");

**Extension Method**

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TElement>> GroupBy<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,string property)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TElement), "groupCol");
        Expression<Func<TElement, string>> lambda;
        if (property.Split('.').Count() > 1)
        {
            Expression body = null;
            foreach (var propertyName in property.Split('.'))
            {
                Expression instance = body;
                if (body == null)
                    instance = parameter;
                body = Expression.Property(instance, propertyName);
            }
            lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, string>>(body, parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            var menuProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, property);
            lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, string>>(menuProperty, parameter);    
        }

        var selector= lambda.Compile();
       return elements.GroupBy(selector);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer consists of two parts:

1. Providing a solution for your problem
2. Educating you on `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` and the differences between the two

#### Part 1: A solution for your immediate problem

The new requirement is not as easily fulfilled as the others were. The main reason for this is that a LINQ query, that groups by a composite key, results in an anonymous type to be created at compile time:

```
source.GroupBy(x => new { x.MenuText, Name = x.Role.Name })
```

This results in a new class with a compiler generated name and two properties `MenuText` and `Name`.
Doing this at runtime would be possible, but is not really feasible, because it would involve emitting IL into a new dynamic assembly.

For my solution I chose a different approach:
Because all the involved properties seem to be of type `string` the key we group by is simply a concatenation of the properties values separated by a semicolon.
So, the expression our code generates is equivalent to the following:

```
source.GroupBy(x => x.MenuText + ";" + x.Role.Name)
```

The code to achieve this looks like this:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, string>> GetGroupKey<T>(
    params string[] properties)
{
    if(!properties.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "At least one property needs to be specified", "properties");

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var propertyExpressions = properties.Select(
        x => GetDeepPropertyExpression(parameter, x)).ToArray();

    Expression body = null;
    if(propertyExpressions.Length == 1)
        body = propertyExpressions[0];
    else
    {
        var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(
            "Concat",
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        var separator = Expression.Constant(";");
        body = propertyExpressions.Aggregate(
            (x , y) => Expression.Call(concatMethod, x, separator, y));
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
}

private static Expression GetDeepPropertyExpression(
    Expression initialInstance, string property)
{
    Expression result = null;
    foreach(var propertyName in property.Split('.'))
    {
        Expression instance = result;
        if(instance == null)
            instance = initialInstance;
        result = Expression.Property(instance, propertyName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This again is an extension of the method I showed in my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680121/572644) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678640/572644) answers.

It works as follows:

1. For each supplied deep property string get the corresponding expression via `GetDeepPropertyExpression`. That is basically the code I added in my previous answer.
2. If only one property has been passed, use it directly as the body of the lambda. The result is the same expression as in my previous answer, e.g. `x => x.Role.Name`
3. If multiple properties have been passed, we concatenate the properties with each other and with a separator in between and use that as the body of the lambda. I chose the semicolon, but you can use whatever you want. Assume we passed three properties (`"MenuText", "Role.Name", "ActionName"`), then the result would look something like this:

   ```
   x => string.Concat(
           string.Concat(x.MenuText, ";", x.Role.Name), ";", x.ActionName)
   ```

   This is the same expression the C# compiler generates for an expression that uses the plus sign to concatenate strings and thus is equivalent to this:

   ```
   x => x.MenuText + ";" + x.Role.Name + ";" + x.ActionName
   ```

#### Part 2: Educating you

The extension method you showed in your question is a very bad idea.
Why? Well, because it works on `IEnumerable<T>`. That means that this group by is *not* executed on the database server but locally in the memory of your application. Furthermore, all LINQ clauses that follow, like a `Where` are executed in memory, too!

If you want to provide extension methods, you need to do that for both `IEnumerable<T>` (in memory, i.e. LINQ to Objects)  and `IQueryable<T>` (for queries that are to be executed on a database, like LINQ to Entity Framework).
That is the same approach Microsoft has chosen. For most LINQ extension methods there exist two variants: One that works on `IEnumerable<T>` and one that works on `IQueryable<T>` which live in two different classes [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) and [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx). Compare the first parameter of the methods in those classes.

So, you what you want to do is something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, TElement>> GroupBy<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> source, params string[] properties)
{
    return source.GroupBy(GetGroupKey<TElement>(properties).Compile());
}

public static IQueryable<IGrouping<string, TElement>> GroupBy<TElement>(
    this IQueryable<TElement> source, params string[] properties)
{
    return source.GroupBy(GetGroupKey<TElement>(properties));
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `Tuple.Create` rather than `String.Concat`, but +1 for a very good, complete answer nonetheless.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I thought about that, too, but I wasn't sure if it is supported by *all* LINQ providers.

Comment: It probably isn't but it would still be more reliable than string concatenation. You could also generate dummy '*anonymous*' types like `Tuple` but which exposed property setters so a `Expression.Bind` would work without having to dynamically generate an assembly like you would for true anonymous types. Of course, then you're limited to a maximum number of properties you can group by.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: How would you generate the dummy anonymous type so that it is supported by the LINQ providers? Whether or not string concatenation is less reliable completely depends on the data.

Comment: Yeah, I'd try to make them as simple as possible, but the provider would still need to support generic DTO's.

Comment: Hi Danie, Please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855416/linq-filter-implementation-with-expressions

Comment: This part is awesome: source.GroupBy(x => x.MenuText + ";" + x.Role.Name)