# How to create an anonymous object as a LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I would like to create the following lambda expression using an Expression Tree in C#:

```
var result = dataList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 })
```

How do I make the anonymous type with two properties as a LINQ Expression (lambdaExp)?

This is what I got so far:

```
IQueryable<GraphData> queryableData = graphDataList.AsQueryable();
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(GraphData), "x");

Expression prop1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "Prop1");
Expression prop2 = Expression.PropertyOrField(pe, "Prop2");

var lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<GraphData, object>>( new { prop1, prop2 } , pe);     //doesn't compile

MethodCallExpression groupByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "GroupBy",
    new Type[] { typeof(GraphData), typeof(object) }, 
    queryableData.Expression,
    lambdaExp);

IQueryable<GraphData> result = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<GraphData>(groupByCallExpression);
```

Comment: What have you tried allready? Show your affords and where you´re stuck. Otherwise we can only guess what your problem might be.

Comment: This answer may resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694121/361842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're writing linq queries and anonymous objects, the compiler is hiding a lot of the magic that it's doing for you. Specifically with anonymous objects, it is also *creating new types* for you.  Unless that type exists somewhere, you will need to create the type manually and use that type in its place.

You can cheat a bit and have the compiler create an object with that type and save a reference to that type. With that, you can generate the necessary expressions to instantiate that object.

One thing to note is that the anonymous objects created for you will have constructors with the parameters in definition order so you just need to invoke that constructor.

```
var keyType = new { Prop1=default(string), Prop2=default(string) }.GetType();
var ctor = keyType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(GraphData), "x");
var keySelector = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.New(ctor,
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Prop1"), // corresponds to Prop1
        Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Prop2")  // corresponds to Prop2
    ),
    param
); // returns non-generic LambdaExpression
```

Do keep in mind that we are dealing with types not known at compile time, so your key selector expression will not have a compile time type.