# Grouping and splitting lists using class properties

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have the following code, which I'd really like to generify so I don't have to call the same LINQ statement dependent on the field.

Is there a way of moving this switch statement up to the ItemViewModel, and calling out to retrieve a generic property  to perform the grouping based on it's string name?

```
    private List<List<ItemViewModel>> SplitItemList(List<List<ItemViewModel>> ItemLists, 
        string groupingField)
    {
        var newItemLists = new List<List<ItemViewModel>>();
        foreach (var itemList in ItemLists)
        {
            var newList = new List<List<ItemViewModel>>();

            switch (groupingField)
            {
                case "problem_description":
                    newList = itemList
                        .GroupBy(a => a.ProblemDescription)
                        .Select(x => x.ToList())
                        .ToList();
                    break;
                case "sw_code":
                    newList = itemList
                        .GroupBy(a => a.SoftwareCode)
                        .Select(x => x.ToList())
                        .ToList();
                    break;
                case "hw_code":
                    newList = itemList
                        .GroupBy(a => a.HardwareCode)
                        .Select(x => x.ToList())
                        .ToList();
                    break;
                case "etc":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            newItemLists.AddRange(newList);
        }
        return newItemLists;
    }
```

Comment: What about just using a lookup-table <groupingField, GroupBySelector>?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically

Comment: Dunken: Using a GroupBySelector sounds interesting, but I can't find any good examples of how to go about doing this. Any chance you can point me to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, try creating the lambda dynamically:

```
public static Func<TIn, TOut> CreateGetter<TIn, TOut>(string propertyName)
{
   var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn));

   var expression = Expression.Property(input, typeof(TIn).GetProperty(propertyName));

   return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(expression, input).Compile();
}
```

Call it like so:

```
        var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        var getter = DynamicLinq.CreateGetter<Tuple<string, string>, string>("Item1");

        var query = list.GroupBy(getter).Select(x => x.ToList());
```

Make sure that the "groupingField" is the exact name of the property though, otherwise this won't work.

EDITED::
As per your comment, I am giving an example of custom attribute usage relevant to your scenario:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FriendlyNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public FriendlyNameAttribute(string friendlyName)
    {
        FriendlyName = friendlyName;
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> PropertyMap;

    static ItemViewModel()
    {
        PropertyMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var myType = typeof (ItemViewModel);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetGetMethod() != null)
            {
                var attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<FriendlyNameAttribute>();

                if (attr == null)
                    continue;

                PropertyMap.Add(attr.FriendlyName, propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GetPropertyMap(string groupingField)
    {
        string propName;

        PropertyMap.TryGetValue(groupingField, out propName);

        return propName; //will return null in case map not found.
    }

    [FriendlyName("problem_description")]
    public string ProblemDescription { get; set; }

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; } // will not be in map
}
```

use it like this:

```
var x = ItemViewModel.GetPropertyMap("problem_description");
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue - it isn't, hence the switch statement. I'd like to stick something in the ItemViewModel that handles that, but I'm not sure what.

I do like the Lamda expression though, will have to read up on that - cheers for your solution.

Comment: why dont you try putting on a custom attribute over your function like:

    [MyAttribute("problem_description")]
    public string ProblemDescription { get; set;}

You can then maintain a dictionary of friendly name gotten from the attribute above (via reflection) so as to minimize cpu costs because of reflection and use dynamic linq as above.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, but is there any chance you could point me to a good example of this? I'm fairly new to C#.