# Linq to DataTable (GROUP BY) when columns are not known

Tags: c#, linq, casting, datatable

I need to create dynamic reports using LINQ against a datatable. The content of the datatable is unknown until the user specifies a given complex query. The following LINQ query would work if the fields are known:

```
var groups = results.AsEnumerable();

var groupList = from g in groups
              group g by g.Field<string>(column) into Grup
                    select new { 
                          GroupedBy = Grup.Key, 
                          CountValue = Grup.Count(r=>r.Field)<int>(countColumn))
                     };
```

However, since I do not know the field type, when a column is of integer type (or different than string) the code will fail at:

```
              group g by g.Field<string>(column) into Grup
```

since it cannot convert int to string. The error is as following:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I was trying to determine the datatype of the column using:

```
results.Columns[column].DataType
```

and then use the datatype for casting, but this does not work apparently. Something similar to this:

```
group g by g.Field<results.Columns[column].DataType>(column) into Grup
```

Comment: use Grup instead of Grupi in your selection.

Comment: Grup / Grupi is just a typo since I shortened the code a lot to post it here. Ill edit it now. The problem still resides.

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just avoid using the extension method and use `Item` instead?

Like:

```
var groups = results.AsEnumerable();

var groupList = from g in groups
          group g by g.Item[column] into Grup
                select new { 
                      GroupedBy = Grupi.Key, 
                      CountValue = Grupi.Countr=>r.Field<int>(countColumn))
                 };
```

Off course, you will incur boxing/unboxing, but given how you're dealing with dynamic output, I think this comes with the territory.

Comment: I am trying this approach but i get the following: "'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found"

Comment: There is a reverence missing i guess!?

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Here's the msdn reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. It's odd, though, if you're using dataset extensions, you should be using System.Data. Make sure you have a using clause for System.Data...