# Linq GroupBy Anonymous Type with Dynamic Properties

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I'm trying to use Linq to group a `List<Person>`.

```
var grouped = personList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Forename, x.Age })
                        .Select(x => new { Description = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

How can I make the properties that'll be Grouped By come from a variable?

```
var groupByProperties = new string[] { "Forename", "Age" };
personList.GroupBy(x => new { ............ })
          .Select(x => new { Description = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

`groupByProperties` will come from user input on a webpage (`<select multiple>`).

I can't quite get my head around the right syntax for `ExpandoObject` or `dynamic`, and aren't sure if I need to use Reflection here.

The Person class might look something like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The result is passed back through to the UI (a Web Page) as JSON, from which a datagrid will be generated. I'll be using javascript to loop through the returned Description object, and generate the grid from that.

Comment: Don't use ExpandoObject in linq as it might leak memory

Comment: It's not clear how you want this to be dynamic - is it still a compile-time choice? Do you need the *whole* group key as the Description property? What are you doing with the result afterwards?

Comment: @dr4cul4: Care to elaborate and/or provide references/evidence?

Comment: Oh and search for dynamic expressions and dynamic parser. Might help you.

Comment: So what problems are you having with the solutions that you have?

Comment: I've worked on project extensively using dynamics. After using ExpandoObject in linq queries they where left in memory until process died. I solved that using simple IDynamicObject implementation that did almost the same thing.

Comment: @Servy, I'm not entirely sure how to create an anonymous type where the properties are coming from (for example) a string array. Edited question to make this clearer - thanks.

Comment: One case of leak is here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783541/expandoobjects-leak-memory-when-used-as-an-idictionary-string-object-to-add-new-properties but I can't find the one with linq as it's a case related to dynamic expressions parser and how linq creates enumerables. (dynamic parser was my implementation but wasn't using dictionary).

Comment: Are you trying to build a pivot table?

Comment: @Aron I'm attempting to make a Report Builder. A 'Summary Report' will be the selected fields with a group and a count(*) - so, yes, sort of!

Comment: Please try Dynamic Linq Library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically

Comment: @DaveSalomon have you considered using SSRS instead of building a square wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to potehin143 for pointing me towards ScottGu's excellent [Linq Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), I've managed to get something running.

I've ended up with a nice one-liner (albeit with slightly bizarre syntax).

```
var fieldsToGroupBy = new string[] { "Forename", "Age" };

var grouped = personList.GroupBy( "new ( "+fieldsToGroupBy.ToCommaSeparatedString("it.")+" )", "it" )
                 .Select("new ( it.Key as Description, it.Count() as Count )");

response.Data = (dynamic)grouped;
```

`ToCommaSeparatedString()` is a simple extension method to change ["Forename","Age"] to "it.Forename, it.Age".

The previous solution (below) wasn't returning the data in quite the format I was hoping. (It was returning *all* data in groups, rather than just a summary.) Credit to Mitsu for this solution (blog posts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2007/12/22/playing-with-linq-grouping-groupbymany.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/02/07/linq-groupbymany-dynamically.aspx)).

```
var groupByProperties = new string[] { "Forename", "Age" };
var grouped = personList.GroupByMany(groupByProperties);
```

The Linq Dynamic Query Library does too much to post even a snippet from. The GroupByMany method:

```
public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
       this IEnumerable<TElement> elements, params string[] groupSelectors)
{
    var selectors =
        new List<Func<TElement, object>>(groupSelectors.Length);
    foreach (var selector in groupSelectors)
    {
        LambdaExpression l =
            DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(
                typeof(TElement), typeof(object), selector);
        selectors.Add((Func<TElement, object>)l.Compile());
    }
    return elements.GroupByMany(selectors.ToArray());
}

public static IEnumerable<GroupResult> GroupByMany<TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
    params Func<TElement, object>[] groupSelectors)
{
    if (groupSelectors.Length > 0)
    {
        var selector = groupSelectors.First();

        //reduce the list recursively until zero
        var nextSelectors = groupSelectors.Skip(1).ToArray();
        return
            elements.GroupBy(selector).Select(
                g => new GroupResult
                {
                    Key = g.Key,
                    Count = g.Count(),
                    Items = g,
                    SubGroups = g.GroupByMany(nextSelectors)
                });
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
            string[] groups = { "Forename", "Surname" };
            var grouped = personList.GroupBy(x => new object[] { Grouper(x, groups) })
                        .Select(x => new { Description = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
        }
        static object[] Grouper(Person person, string[] groups)
        {
            List<object> results = new List<object>();
            foreach (string group in groups)
            {
                switch (group)
                {
                    case "Forename" :
                        results.Add(person.Forename);
                        break;
                    case "Surname":
                        results.Add(person.Surname);
                        break;
                    case "Age":
                        results.Add(person.Age);
                        break;
                    case "Gender":
                        results.Add(person.Gender);
                        break;
                }
            }


            return results.ToArray();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `EqualityComparer<object[]>.Default` will use the reference of the array as it's identity, not the values of the array, so using this solution every single value you're grouping on will always be unique.