# Distinct values from a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects from which I want another list of distinct values depending on an array.

To explain my problem with an example

Original List

```
// Class of the object
class Obj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

// List of the object
List<Obj> objects = new List<Obj>();

//Values in the list
Obj a = new Obj();
a.Name = "Jack";
a.Surname = "Grey";
a.Address = "Sheffield";
objects.Add(a);

Obj b = new Obj();
b.Name = "John";
b.Surname = "Grey";
b.Address = "Sheffield";
objects.Add(b);

Obj c = new Obj();
c.Name = "Jack";
c.Surname = "Grey";
c.Address = "London";
objects.Add(c);
```

Now I want another list which would have distinct values depending upon an array

```
string[] ColArray = new string[2] {"Name", "Surname"};
```

How can I do something like this? Basically have another list with distinct columns from the array

```
List<Obj> NewList = objects.GroupBy( what to put here ).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

My NewList would contain objects of a and b

Comment: Do you want to distinct objects value?

Comment: Yes I want distinct objects depending on the column values. The columns are defined in the array

Comment: Distinct on what column, name field alone

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically

Comment: No - all columns defined in the array. The array values are defined runtime.

Comment: Check the solution using `System.Linq.Dynamic` Nuget package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `System.Linq.Dynamic` as follows:

1. Get the Nuget Package

Following would be the code (On LinqPad, otherwise replace `Dump` call with `Console.WriteLine`):

```
string[] ColArray = new string[] {"Name","Surname"};

string groupingString = "new(" + string.Join(",",ColArray) + ")";

var groupedObjectData = objects.GroupBy(groupingString,"it");

foreach (IGrouping<DynamicClass, Obj> objGroup in groupedObjectData)
{
    objGroup.Select(x => x).Dump();
}
```

**Important Points:**

1. ColArray can be modified to have 1 or more than 1 column, it will automatically adjust
2. Grouping key by default is a `DynamicClass`, and grouped value is an `obj class` type
3. "it" in grouping statement is Dynamic Linq keyword for selecting all the Columns, instead of specific columns

**Result:**

[image]