# LINQ Group by; How to make it flexible

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

considering the bit of code at the bottom, this is my problem:

I want to be able to group revenue based on input, e.g.:
- Year
- Month
- Week
- Units
etc.

Do I need to make a var for each combination (and change the Group by accordingly) or can I make something in which the Group by variables are flexible. Meaning that I can get the `LocationRevenue` on the level of `input`  for example: week, or month, or year; or year+month together, week+month together or any other combination.

```
var locationRevenues = revenues
.GroupBy(g => new { Location = g.Location, Month = DateTimeHelper.GetMonth(g.Date)})
.Select(r => new
{
    Location = r.Key,
    RevenueTotal = r.Sum(i => i.RevenueAmount),

})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically) what you´re after?

Comment: I think so yes! seems more advanced than I can handle right now :(

Comment: You may delete your question if the linked one provides what you´ve searched for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each time you add new `groupBy` select inside `groupby` clause and press `Ctrl + R + M` and generate new method. You may pass this as a parameter.

```
Do(Func<TSource, TKey>)

var locationRevenues = revenues
                .GroupBy(Func())
                .Select(r => new
                {
                    Location = r.Key,
                    RevenueTotal = r.Sum(i => i.RevenueAmount),

                })
                .ToList();


private static Func<Revenues, object> Func()
{
    return g => new { Location = g.Location, Month = 9 };
}
```