# Is it possible to add GroupBy to a IQueryable<T> query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to genericize some repeated stuff but struggling with this. I don't even know if it's even possible. I put what I need inside the code block but I'd be happy to clarify if need be. Any help is appreciated.

```
  public static async Task<object> LoadData<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string RequestGroup) where T : class
  {
     //this works
     //var Groupped = query.AsNoTracking().ToList().GroupBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue(RequestGroup)).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() });

     //How can I achieve this?
     var Groupped = query.GroupBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue(RequestGroup)).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

     return new { Data = Groupped };
  }

  public async Task<JsonResult> GetData()
  {
     var query = _context.Samples.AsQueryable();
     return Json(await LoadData(query, "Description"));
  }

  public class Sample
  {
     public int SampleID { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
  }

  #region Extensions
  public static object GetPropertyValue(this object obj, string name)
  {
     foreach (string part in name.Split('.'))
     {
        if (obj == null) { return null; }

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part);
        if (info == null) { return null; }

        obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);
     }
     return obj;
  }

  public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string name)
  {
     object retval = GetPropertyValue(obj, name);
     if (retval == null) { return default(T); }

     // throws InvalidCastException if types are incompatible
     return (T)retval;
  }
  #endregion
```

Comment: How many possible values of `RequestGroup` are there?

Comment: you can use expression, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678197/linq-grouping-dynamically

Comment: it's limitless. Whatever the properties of the class passed in T.

Comment: coder_b, I used one of those solutions in that link but it queries all the rows from database and do the grouping later which I am trying to avoid. `var Groupped =  query.GroupBy(GetColumnName<T>(RequestGroup.Selector).Compile()).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks coder_b, I used another response from the link you provided and got what I am looking for. Here is the answer if anyone else needs it:

```
  public static async Task<object> LoadData<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string RequestGroup) where T : class
  {
     //this works
     //var Groupped = query.AsNoTracking().ToList().GroupBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue(RequestGroup)).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() });

     //How can I achieve this?
     //var Groupped = query.GroupBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue(RequestGroup)).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

     //Answer
     var Groupped = query.GroupBy(GetGroupKey<T>(RequestGroup)).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Distinct().Count() }).ToList();

     return new { Data = Groupped };
  }

  public async Task<JsonResult> GetData()
  {
     var query = _context.Samples.AsQueryable();
     return Json(await LoadData(query, "Description"));
  }

  public class Sample
  {
     public int SampleID { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
  }

  #region Extensions
  private static Expression<Func<T, string>> GetGroupKey<T>(string property)
  {
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     var body = Expression.Property(parameter, property);
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, parameter);
  }
  #endregion
```